# Problem with JSON RPC on RPI and calling a method

Tags: python, request, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, json-rpc

I got a raspberry pi with a json rpc server running on it. i used this module: https://github.com/bcb/jsonrpcserver

Everything is working fine when I only make a request to the following method:

```
@method
def ping(): 
    return "pong"
```

But when I want to go further and do other functions and things like

```
@method
def changeDisplay(): 
    self.led.clear_display()
```

Even when I do

```
@method 
def ping():
    self.helloworld()

def helloworld():
    print("helloworld")
```

then I get a 500 error without further explanation.

```
request("http://192.168.2.5:5000", "ping")
```

Request looks like above I am stuck and have tried many different things.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Tijn\PycharmProjects\JSONrpcTest\venv\lib\site-packages\jsonrpcclient\__init__.py", line 8, in request
    return HTTPClient(endpoint).request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tijn\PycharmProjects\JSONrpcTest\venv\lib\site-packages\apply_defaults\decorators.py", line 13, in wrapper
    return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tijn\PycharmProjects\JSONrpcTest\venv\lib\site-packages\jsonrpcclient\client.py", line 232, in request
    validate_against_schema=validate_against_schema,
  File "C:\Users\Tijn\PycharmProjects\JSONrpcTest\venv\lib\site-packages\apply_defaults\decorators.py", line 13, in wrapper
    return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tijn\PycharmProjects\JSONrpcTest\venv\lib\site-packages\jsonrpcclient\client.py", line 171, in send
    self.validate_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Tijn\PycharmProjects\JSONrpcTest\venv\lib\site-packages\jsonrpcclient\clients\http_client.py", line 48, in validate_response
    raise ReceivedNon2xxResponseError(response.raw.status_code)
jsonrpcclient.exceptions.ReceivedNon2xxResponseError: Received 500 status code
```

Pastebin of full code:
https://pastebin.com/dgFEUBNp

---

**UPDATE**

Think it has something to do with the server not being async. All prints after server start are not printed

Comment: what is the request function? is it python requests?

Comment: It's a python request indeed. (from jsonrpcclient import request)

Comment: I meant the python requests module not a function from jsonrpcclient, but now I know, its most likely a 500 error is given because whichever function you are calling e.g. `self.led.clear_display()` is failing.

Comment: Made an edit. It's not in the function, because even a simple hello world which prints it is not working.

Comment: whats the traceback?

Comment: also do you need to ensure you `return print("helloworld") `

Comment: Got that ensured. Added traceback but it's minimal.

Comment: Agreed that is a pointless traceback (thanks python) I have suffered these errors (500) many times with Flask/Quart and it often comes down to a simple errror like its not accepting a variable (maybe used a reserved word somewhere) otherwise Im sorry I cant help

Comment: Added pastebin with full code, maybe you could take a look. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok ill take a look.

Comment: Note that the traceback is from the *client* - your actual error occurs on the *server*, you should try and get the traceback from there.

Comment: There is no traceback only http error code unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

The methods of your class do not receive a `self` parameter, yet attempt to use it:

```
class Bartender(MenuDelegate):
    ...
    @method
    def ping():
        self.changeDsplay()  # name `self` is not defined
        print (" TOkm")
        return " ewa"
```

The docs for `jsonrpcserver` and [the source](https://github.com/bcb/jsonrpcserver/blob/master/jsonrpcserver/methods.py) do not suggest that `method` can properly handle classes and their methods. It seems that you have to add the *bound* methods an instance, not the unbound methods of the class.

```
class Bartender(MenuDelegate):
    ...
    # regular unbound method taking `self` parameter
    def ping(self):
        self.changeDsplay()
        print (" TOkm")
        return " ewa"

    def run(self):
        # register bound methods *of this instance*
        method(ping=self.ping)
        ...
```

Comment: Sorry, was a tryout. In my original code ping did receive a self param. Only difference is that it outputs a 400 error

Comment: @tijn167 Neither the code on pastebin nor in your answer show that. Please post your actual code! Also take a look at the registration of bound methods I added.

Comment: Tried your method, still nothing changed. Think it has something to do with using non async. Because everything after server start isn't executed

Comment: Your method did in fact work with a little tweak. I also started the server in the run method and thats what did the job. Now just got too check if the physical and mobile work together. Thanks!